# Нулевая инициализация

Tags: c++

В каких случаях происходит инициализация нулями и в каких нет?

Comment: Смотря чего. Для инициализации участка памяти, например, существуют функции стандартной библиотеки(calloc как альтернатива malloc, к примеру).

Comment: Мне интересны все возможные случаи инициализации в с++, гугл не помог или я не так гуглил.

Comment: А мне вот [помог](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) гугл

Comment: Ну там же не все случаи.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Инициализация нулями ([zero-initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#6)) применяется в трех случаях:

1) Переменные со статическим и потоковым временем хранения (static/thread storage duration), перед тем как для них производится любая другая инициализация.
Сюда входят переменные, объявленные с помощью ключевых слов `thread_local`, `static`, а также глобальные переменные.

```
thread_local int a;
int b;
struct S {
  void f() {
    static int c;
  }
  static int d;
};
int S::d;
```

2) При инициализации значением ([value-initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8)), если тип не является классом (`class` или `struct`), и не является массивом.

```
union U { int a; float b; };
void f(int, U);

f(int(), U());
```

3) Элементы массива `char`, [для которых нет инициализаторов](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string):

```
char a[5] = "123"; // a[3] и a[4] будут использованы нулями.
```

Более подробно можно прочитать на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: А как же массивы? `int a[16]={0};`

Comment: А `char` чем особенный?

Comment: @Abyx en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization, там пишут object в таком странном контексте как будто это понятие включает в себя и класс и обычный примитивный тип. Верно ли это?

Comment: @Kioqps, да это нормально: «The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. **An object is a
region of storage**.» Standard C++ [intro.object] p1

Comment: @ixSci , я нашел стандарт с++, но никак не могу найти раздел об инициализаторах. Ткните пожалуйста, умоляю :D

Comment: @Kioqps, поиск по pdf ->intro.object. Ну или секция 1.8, самый первый пункт.

Comment: @ixSci , а чем отличается variable от object? Тем что variable именованная?

Comment: @MrPrank, если очень грубо, то — да. Подробнее можно [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987259/why-is-a-non-static-data-member-reference-not-a-variable) глянуть

Answer (score 5):

Нулями инициализируются переменные, расположенные в статической памяти, а переменные, расположенные в автоматической памяти (стеке) не инициализируются.

Comment: При обьявлении класса в стеке (локального,  не ссылки на класс) вызывается конструктор класса. Если конструктор делает "очистку", то да.

Answer (score 4):

Самый заковыристый момент с конструкторами по-умолчанию. Если конструктор по-умолчанию определен компилятором неявно, то при вызове его со скобками зануление выполняется, а без скобок не выполняется.

У меня на эту тему была проблема с классом [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) который по стандарту не имеет каких-либо явных конcтрукторов. Так вот, следующий код ожидал зануление и был ошибочный:

```
typedef std::array<unsigned char, 16> Bytes;

auto block = Bytes;  // в массиве муссор
```

А этот правильный:

```
auto block = Bytes(); // в массиве нули
```

Правда в моем случае дело усугубилось еще и тем, что волшебный VC2012 в отладочной сборке выполнял зануление для первого варианта, а в выпускной нет. Поэтому я не сразу догадался проверить конструктор.